# How do I maximize an already open gnome-terminal window from command line?

Tags: command-line, gnome

I know you can open an new gnome-terminal maximized by using:

```
gnome-terminal --maximize
```

That is not my question. Is there a command that I can use to maximize the current terminal where I am in. I know you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> to maximize it, but I want to do it from the terminal using a command.

Answer (score 23):

You can use `wmctrl`:

```
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b toggle,maximized_vert,maximized_horz
```

or `xdotool`:

```
xdotool windowsize $(xdotool getactivewindow) 100% 100%
```

For more info, see [`man wmctrl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/wmctrl.1.html) and [`man xdotool`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/xdotool.1.html).

If you don't have these packages installed, you can install them using the following comand:

```
sudo apt-get install wmctrl xdotool
```

Comment: I used `wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b add,maximized_vert,maximized_horz` to prevent toggling an already maximized window to an unmaximized one.

Also, I've used `if command -v wmctrl >/dev/null 2>&1 then echo 'y' fi` as per http://stackoverflow.com/a/677212/165330 .

Comment: dunno about the former, but the latter doesn't maximize, it changes the window's size. different thing.

Comment: Trivial note, if a monitor is being specified using x/y dimensions, and the window is already maximised on the non-targetted monitor, combining the dimensions with `-e` and maximising with `-b add,max...` will not switch the monitor (it can't move it if it's already maximised)

Comment: I ended using both tools ,wmctrl and xdootool with couple of aliases.
`alias wmax="xdotool key ctrl+super+Up"`
`alias wmin="xdotool key ctrl+super+Down key ctrl+super+Down"`
`alias wl="xdotool key ctrl+super+Left"`
`alias wr="xdotool key ctrl+super+Right"`
`alias wt=" wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b toggle,maximized_vert,maximized_horz "`

Comment: I've tried the above commands and they work nicely, but I was wondering if there's also a way to bring a terminal back to it's default size when maximized? I know setting the x% y% with the xdotool would be an option but maybe there's something simpler?

Comment: none of them maximize the window, they just change the size.

Answer (score 7):

You can send keystroke combinations directly to a window using the `xdotool` command-line X11 automation tool e.g.

```
xdotool key ctrl+super+Up
```

In general it is necessary to specify the target window to receive the keystrokes, but the default is to send them to the active window so in this case no additional window target is required

The `xdotool` package is not installed by default but you can add it from your favourite package manager / software center or using apt-get

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

Then edit your ~/.bash_aliases file and add the following line

```
alias wmax='xdotool key ctrl+super+Up'
```

This will enable you to max any future screen with wmax

Comment: I ended using both tools ,wmctrl and xdootool with couple of aliases. alias wmax="xdotool key ctrl+super+Up" alias wmin="xdotool key ctrl+super+Down key ctrl+super+Down" alias wl="xdotool key ctrl+super+Left" alias wr="xdotool key ctrl+super+Right" alias wt=" wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b toggle,maximized_vert,maximized_horz "

Answer (score 4):

On Ubuntu 14.04 while in the terminal window, just pressing <kbd>F11</kbd> does the thing.

Comment: The OP was asking about using the command line, not pressing keys...

Comment: Right. Anyway...

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu 18.04 this works (e.g. added those lines to the end of .bashrc; g might stand for gui, just to avoid conflicts with other similar names):

```
alias gmax='xdotool key super+Up'
alias gwin='xdotool key super+Down'
alias gmin='xdotool key super+h'
```

Please not that after calling 'gmin' on the shell your focus will go to somewhere else. If using a script then you dont have to care. At the keyboard you have to use e.g. your pointing device for returning to your console.

Evidently the installation of the used 'xdotool' needs to be performed one time for the machine:

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `xdotool` version 2021x (currently, on Ubuntu it's still at 2016x), you can `windowstate` like this:

```
xdotool getactivewindow windowstate  --add MAXIMIZED_HORZ windowstate --add MAXIMIZED_VERT
```

Details:

```
Usage: windowstate [options] [window=%1]
If no window is given, %1 is used. See WINDOW STACK in xdotool(1)
--add property  - add a property
--remove property - remove a property
--toggle property - toggle a property
property can be one of 
MODAL, STICKY, MAXIMIZED_VERT, MAXIMIZED_HORZ, SHADED, SKIP_TASKBAR, 
SKIP_PAGER, HIDDEN, FULLSCREEN, ABOVE, BELOW, DEMANDS_ATTENTION
```

Answer (score -1):

it's so simple, just press F11 in your keyboard.
F11

Comment: duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/a/614793/